# The instance member 'localrender' can't be accessed in an initializer. Try replacing the reference to the instance member with a different expression

Tags: flutter, dart

I just want to add widgets to ListView dynamically when an event occurs. So What I do is created an array set the first element when an event occurs I will update the list and it will change the UI. but I got **The instance member 'localVideoRenderer' can't be accessed in an initializer. Try replacing the reference to the instance member with a different expression**

```
RTCVideoRenderer _localVideoRenderer = RTCVideoRenderer();
  
  var renders = [];

  final List<Widget> names = 
  [
    Container(
      key: new Key("local"),
      margin: new EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(5.0, 5.0, 5.0, 5.0),
      decoration: new BoxDecoration(color: Colors.black),
      child: RTCVideoView(_localVideoRenderer),
    ),
  ];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to access an instance variable in another instance variable in the initializer.
Try initializing `names` to an empty list by default and update it within a overridden function `void initState()`

Comment: I am checking on it